# Hecke correspondence and the trace map of differential forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $k$ be a field, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ smooth geometrically connected curves, and $f: Z \to X$, $g : Z \to Y$ finite morphisms.
Suppose that $f$ is separable.
Then we have $f_* \circ g^* : \Gamma(Y, \Omega_Y) \to \Gamma(Z, \Omega_Z) \to \Gamma(X, \Omega_X)$.

By definition, the Hecke operator is this map for certain morphisms.

The definition of $f_*$ is as follows:
Now $\Omega_{Z, \zeta} = \Omega_{X, \xi} \otimes_{k(X)} k(Z)$.
Using this, $f_*$ is defined as $\Gamma(Z, \Omega_Z) \to \Omega_{Z, \zeta} = \Omega_{X, \xi} \otimes_{k(X)} k(Z) \to \Omega_{X, \xi}$,
where $\Omega_{X, \xi} \otimes_{k(X)} k(Z) \to \Omega_{X, \xi}$ is $1 \otimes \operatorname{tr}$.

But why this map factors through $\Gamma(X, \Omega_X)$?
I've found a reference ([Zannier - A note on traces of differential forms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404998000450) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1716049))), but its proof is too long.
I wonder whether we can give a more elementary proof (using $\dim = 1$).

And I've heard that this $f_*$ is the Serre dual of $H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X) \to H^1(Z, \mathscr{O}_Z)$.
Is this true?
And how can I show these two maps are the same?

Comment: You say "The definition of $f_*$ is:  Now $\Omega_{Z, \zeta} = \Omega_{X, \xi} \otimes_{k(X)} k(Z)$."  Is that intentional?

Comment: @LSpice It's because of lack of my English skills. I edited it. And thank you for editing.

Comment: The article of Zannier is incorrect.

Comment: It's a pity that neither the journal web-page for Zannier's paper, nor the MathSciNet review, has any kind of note attached acknowledging the error.

Comment: @JasonStarr So does not the map $f_*$ factor through $\Gamma(X, \Omega_X)?$

Comment: @k.j. You left out a hypothesis that $f$ is generically smooth.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for pointing out.
So, for a separable $f$, does $f_*$ factor through $\Gamma(X, \Omega)$?
I want its (elementary) proof.